# How to use PCA on test set (code)

Tags: r, pca

I'm trying to use PCA to select some K principal components to work with.

I understand that one should NOT re-run PCA on the testing set, but use the eigenvectors \ PC's found when modeling the training set.

**I Have 2 CSV's - One is training set,**

**The other a test set (without the label per record)**

PCA process on the **training set** is done with the following code:

```
# Load CSV file
train_set.init_data <- read.csv("D:\\train.csv", header = TRUE)

# Remove identifier and respone variables (ID, and SalePrice):
train_set.vars <- subset(train_set.init_data, select = -c(Id, SalePrice))

# Convert catergorical variables into numerical using dummy variables:
library(dummies)
train_set.vars_dummy <- dummy.data.frame(train_set.vars, sep = ".")

# Principal Component Analysis:
train_set.prin_comp <- prcomp(train_set.vars_dummy, scale. = T)

# Choose some K components
????

# Run linear regression model based on PC's
<.....>
```

After I'm done building a model using the training set, I would need to load the testing set and run my prediction model on it.

The difficulties I'm having, in terms of 'How to code it?':

1. How to extract K (Will be chosen based on scree plot) PC's after running PCA (on the training set), so the modeling for the training set will be based on those? (planning on linear regression)
2. How to use K extracted PC's when wanting to run the model built on an actual testing set?
3. Should I zero-mean the features in the testing set first, or scale STD of them?
   For the training set, I understand `prcomp` method already does that for me, so I'm not sure if I should do it manually on the testing set.
4. Should I transform categorical variables of test set into numerical using dummy variables, as I've done with the training set?

I **DO** understand the basic - those same operations applied to the training set, should be applied to the testing set as well.

But - I'm not sure exactly what that means in terms of code.

Thanks

Comment: Not the right forum to ask this. You may try [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @KarthikArumugham , When asked this on Cross Validated, I've also received a comment saying its not the right forum. See here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262698/r-how-to-use-principal-components-on-test-set?noredirect=1#comment502651_262698

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using the `USArrests` dataset to give you an idea on the sequence of steps to be followed to perform PCA on test data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
data(USArrests)
train <- USArrests %>% rownames_to_column(var = "rowname")
test <- USArrests %>% rownames_to_column(var = "rowname")
```

**Approach 1** - Combined train & test

```
# Join train and test set
df <- bind_rows("train" = train, "test" = test, .id="group")
# Run Principal Components Analysis
pc <- prcomp(df %>% select(-rowname, -group), scale = TRUE)
# Plot ScreePlot
pc_var <- (pc$sdev^2)/sum(pc$sdev^2)
plot(pc_var, xlab = "Principal Component", ylab = "Proportion of Variance Explained", type = "b")
# Extract PCs (e.g. 1st 3 PCs)
df <- augment(pc,df) %>% select(group, rowname, .fittedPC1 : .fittedPC3)
# Split into train and test
train <- df %>% filter(group == "train") %>% select(-group)
test <-  df %>% filter(group == "test") %>% select(-group)
```

In this approach the test data may leak into the train data.

**Approach 2** - Using `predict()` to transform test data from PCA loadings of train data

```
# Run Principal Components Analysis
pc <- prcomp(train %>% select(-rowname), scale = TRUE)
# Extract PCs  (e.g. 1st 3 PCs)
train <- tbl_df(pc1$x) %>% select(PC1:PC3)
test <- tbl_df(predict(pc, newdata = test %>% select(-rowname))) %>% select(PC1:PC3)
```

This approach is more robust compared to the earlier one.

Comment: Thanks, That seems to answer some of my thoughts. So to be clear -

1. Load training & testing set CSV
2. Remove response variable from the training set
3. Combine both sets together
4. Perform PCA

Is that flow correct?
And still I have some of the questions unclear to me - Could you please explain:
1. The last two lines which use `df` to split back - Will this actually represent my data using the PC's?

2. After the split - train and test contains the transformed features? So I could attach the label back (to the train set), and use linear regression on it ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but as looking through: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/practical-guide-principal-component-analysis-python/

The author states just the opposite of what you're saying:

`We should not combine the train and test set to obtain PCA components of whole data at once. Because, this would violate the entire assumption of generalization since test data would get ‘leaked’ into the training set. In other words, the test data set would no longer remain ‘unseen’. Eventually, this will hammer down the generalization capability of the model.`

Comment: @Adiel. Thanks. Fixed it. What I meant was that you shouldn't do a PCA on train and test separately - The second caveat as per the author.

Comment: Thank you friend. Mind if I annoy you a bit more - 1. Why does `rownames_to_column` is needed? couldn't figure it out. 2. `augment` isn't needed for the 2nd approach?

Thanks

Comment: @Adiel `rownames_to_column()` is only required if you have some data stored as rownames, like in this case of USArrests data. You can use `augment()` if you want to retain some columns from the dataframe, like `rownames` in this case.

Comment: And if my data is just a simple CSV with headers (Each column is a different feature, each row is simply one record)? The code parts of `%>% select(-rowname)` isn't needed when extracting PCs, like your 2nd approach example?